# From JavaScript source: Can you tell me about the meaning of the operator?

Tags: javascript

```
// @flow
export const LETSEE_LOADED: 'LETSEE_LOADED' = 'LETSEE_LOADED';
export const START_LOADING: 'START_LOADING' = 'START_LOADING';
export const STOP_LOADING: 'STOP_LOADING' = 'STOP_LOADING';

export const letseeLoad = () => ({ type: LETSEE_LOADED });
export const startLoading = () => ({ type: START_LOADING });
export const stopLoading = () => ({ type: STOP_LOADING });
```

Please resolve any questions that your company has encountered while analyzing JavaScript source.

I am wondering what the meaning of the: operator next to export const LETSEE_LOADED in the above source. It does not seem to be a ternary operator.

You can just say export const LETSEE_LOADED = 'LETSEE_LOADED', but what about the: operator?

Answer (score 0):

The `:` says that the *type* of the variable is a exact string `LETSEE_LOADED` and only a value containing that exact string can be assigned to the variable. The variable is declared as const, so it can't be modified *after the assignment*, but you can misstype the value of the variable *at the initialization*, so why in the combination with the `const` the type is also provided.

Comment: Thanks ^ _ ^.  I think I need to learn more about type scripts. !!